# How does Java handle initializing arrays made of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm learning java and for a particular application I am creating, I am initializing a 2D array of objects. The particular object that would occupy the array when initialized changes multiple variables in its no args constructor. I am wondering if when the array is declared java initializes each variable in all elements of the array:

```
private Piece positions[][]=new Piece[8][8];
```

Or is it necessary to do this?

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            Positions[i][j]=new Piece();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java will initialize the value of an element in the array to the datatype's default value.

The [JLS, Section 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), covers default values:

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> - For type byte, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (byte)0.
> - For type short, the default value is zero, that is, the value of (short)0.
> - For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
> - For type long, the default value is zero, that is, 0L.
> - For type float, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0f.
> - For type double, the default value is positive zero, that is, 0.0d.
> - For type char, the default value is the null character, that is, '\u0000'.
> - For type boolean, the default value is false.
> - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null.

For primitive types, this is `0` or `false`, and for reference types, the default value is `null`.  So yes, you need to initialize each element as in your last code example, with `new`, else it will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Piece positions[][]=new Piece[8][8];
```

This initializes an array of 8x8 `Piece` references, not the elements contained. The array will be `null-initialized`, indeed every cell will contain `null`.